# response.redirect not working within update panel using timer tick

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I need to redirect page using a button within a update panel. but when I try this It didn't work for me. can anyone help me on this??/. Please Find My Code Below.

```
   <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="345px"></asp:Label><br />
                    <br />    
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>     
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>        
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />

                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
              <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="500">
                    </asp:Timer>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="344px" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;</div>
    </form>
              </body>
```

My Code Behind Code

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        public void imgBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/HotelResult.aspx");

        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ImageButton testbtn = new ImageButton();
            testbtn.ID = "testbtnid";
            testbtn.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.imgBtn_Click);
            testbtn.ImageUrl = "images/book-btn.png";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(testbtn);
        }



    }
```

Comment: Do you want full page reload, or to load new page inside update panel?

Comment: want to reload a full page

Comment: Why are you disabling the timer when it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `ImageButton` is added to the page *only* after timer tick. If you want server-side handlers to be invoked for such dynamically added controls, you have to added the to the page on every postback. Here is how it can be done using key view state:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    bool? addHotelResultButton = ViewState["AddHotelResultButton"] as bool?;
    if (addHotelResultButton.HasValue && addHotelResultButton.Value)
    {
        AddHotelResultButton();
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["AddHotelResultButton"] = true;
    AddHotelResultButton();
}

protected void AddHotelResultButton()
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    ImageButton testbtn = new ImageButton();
    testbtn.ID = "testbtnid";
    testbtn.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.imgBtn_Click);
    testbtn.ImageUrl = "images/heroAccent.png";
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(testbtn);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this :

- Put your button inside your updatePanel and disable it
- Put it as a trigger inside the `<triggers>` tag
- When the tick event come, enable your button